# How to Convert JSON to be readable by Excel (Already Flattened)?

Tags: python, json, excel, data-science

Here is a snippet of the code I have right now:

```
  '0_parcel_mapicon': None,
  '0_parcel_mapiconselected': None,
  '0_parcel_sections_0_0_0_buildingId': 123456,
  '0_parcel_sections_0_0_0_id': 123,
  '0_parcel_sections_0_0_0_LandUseCode': 'R00',
  '0_parcel_sections_0_0_0_Neighborhood': 'S110',
  '0_parcel_sections_0_0_0_landUseCodeDescription': 'SINGLE',
  '0_parcel_sections_0_0_0_LandSize': '1 LOT',
  '0_parcel_sections_0_0_0_Exemption': None,
  '0_parcel_sections_0_0_0_Tax_MunDist': 'NYC',
  '0_parcel_sections_0_0_0_SaleDate': '05/10/2021',
...
  '1_parcel_mapicon': None,
  '1_parcel_mapiconselected': None,
  '1_parcel_sections_0_0_0_buildingId': 56789,
  '1_parcel_sections_0_0_0_id': 321,
  '1_parcel_sections_0_0_0_LandUseCode': 'Z00',
  '1_parcel_sections_0_0_0_Neighborhood': 'D110',
  '1_parcel_sections_0_0_0_landUseCodeDescription': 'SINGLE',
  '1_parcel_sections_0_0_0_LandSize': '2 LOT',
  '1_parcel_sections_0_0_0_Exemption': None,
  '1_parcel_sections_0_0_0_Tax_MunDist': 'NYC',
  '1_parcel_sections_0_0_0_SaleDate': '09/10/2021',
...etc
```

This is in JSON format but has been converted to be a "flatter" file, incrementing each section by 1 as it goes down the JSON. I now need to be able to take this file and import into Excel in order to perform more advanced filtering. Unfortunately, Excel does not easily import this and treats each section as if its a new individual column (delimited by a colon).

I have tried to remove the incremeter from the Python code but by doing so it just exported one entity. Below is the code I used to flatten the data:

```
import json
import requests

def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        # If the Nested key-value
        # pair is of dict type
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
                # If the Nested key-value
        # pair is of list type
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out
```

Is there any way to get this to be more acceptable to Excel?

Comment: VBA and Power Query (both available in Excel), have tools for importing regular JSON files. Perhaps one of those would be more useful than dealing with a pre-processed file.

Answer (score 1):

you can use pandas to convert between the formats:
convert json to dictionary:

```
data = json.load('json_file path')
```

and use pandas to save it to excel

```
df_dict = pd.DataFrame.from_dict('json converted to dict')
df_dict.to_excel('Path to output excel file', index=False)
```

Comment: How is it read into Excel? With the appropriate columns/rows?

Comment: it save the data to excel file, im using dictionary keys as headers and the table data as values but you can look into "to_excel" to get more info how the output will be.